# restore dell T1500 software to factory settings

Tags: windows-8, boot, dell-precision

after upgrading the windows 7 of my dell precision T1500 to windows 8 (made this a long time ago without problems), i can't manage to restore the system default :

Every advice i read about system restore talk about a Advanced Boot Options menu binded on F8, with a "Repair Your Computer" option. I don't get that on my boot options (my trigger key is F12)

I ran the dell diagnostic without effects, and i booted on the last device of the boot option (pre boot system assessment), which ran a CPU test.

Since i tried all the option of the boot menu, where can i find a way to restore the system defaults ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Restore the machine back to how you got it (with Windows 7?)  Is there a recovery partition on the drive still?

Comment: yes i'm trying to restore its original settings, with windows 7. my windows 8 is broke for an unknown reason, i can't access the configuration panel, side menus or any windows applications except the desktop (i go to desktop right after login, the metro UI is not accessible too)

I don't know if i have a recovery partition on the drive, how can i see it ?